# What is the correct syntax to send Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to multiple topics via condition

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

Simply I want to use the Google Cloud Functions to send notifications to devices that subscribe to a combination of topics.

The documentation says:

> "'TopicA' in topics && ('TopicB' in topics || 'TopicC' in topics)"

What I tried to do is:

```
var topicsConditions = `'${type}' in topics && ('${area}' in topics || '${city}' in topics)`;

// Send a message to devices subscribed to the provided topic.
admin.messaging().sendToCondition(topicsConditions, notificationPayload)
  .then(function(response) {
    // See the MessagingTopicResponse reference documentation for the
    // contents of response.
    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
  });
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Error sending message: { Error: Invalid argument provided. Raw server response: "Invalid "condition" field: only support 'topics' conditions
>   ". Status code: 400.
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
>       at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
>       at new FirebaseMessagingError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
>       at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request.js:115:23
>       at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
>     errorInfo: 
>      { code: 'messaging/invalid-argument',
>        message: 'Invalid argument provided. Raw server response: "Invalid "condition" field: only support \'topics\' conditions\n". Status code: 400.' },
>     codePrefix: 'messaging' }

Anyone can direct me to the correct syntax?

Edit: The log output of the topics is:

> Topic conditions = 'MyType+' in topics && ('Giza, Egypt ' in topics || 'القاهرة الكبرى' in topics)

Comment: Add `console.log(topicsConditions)` to your code to see what the actual value is. Add the output to your post. Maybe `type`, `area`, or `city` are not what you expect.

Comment: For other readers, here is [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_condition) referenced in the post.

Comment: I did actually, I just removed it from the code snippet because I did not think it is relevant.

The output is as I expected, but the thing is, I am not sure if this is what FCM expected. Exact log output below

Topic conditions = 'MyType+' in topics && ('Giza, Egypt ' in topics || 'القاهرة الكبرى' in topics)

Comment: i given answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333944/6925888

Answer (score 5):

The characters that may be used in a topic name are limited to:

- lowercase letters `a` to `z`
- uppercase letters `A` to `Z`
- digits `0` to `9`
- characters `-`   `_`  `.`  `~`  `%`

Your topic names contain invalid characters `+`, `,`, space, and Arabic.

Further details are in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_messages_to_topics):

> Developers can choose any topic name that matches the regular
>   expression: "[a-zA-Z0-9-_.~%]+"

An example of a valid condition string is:

```
var topicsConditions = "'Aswan' in topics && ('Giza' in topics || 'Cairo' in topics)";
```

I successfully used this string in a call to `admin.messaging().sendToCondition()`

Comment: Thanks @Bob. I tried removing arabic characters and I'm still getting the exact same error. Any idea how the conditions string should look like?

Comment: Your string must have other invalid characters.  Did you remove the `+`, `,` and space?  See the update to my answer.  I just ran a test with that string, so I know it is valid.

Comment: I think you are right. I hardcoded some variables as follows: var topicsConditions = `'NasrCity' in topics && 'TopicPlus' in topics`; And its not working. Will try it with variables next. Thank you very much Bob

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use with variables then you may use like this

```
const condition = `\'${OLDUSERS}\' in topics || \'${CURRENTLYBOOKED}\' in topics`;
```

And use send method in this case.