# What is the correct syntax to send FCM notification to multiple topics via condition using node.js?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to send fcm notification from my node.js server to android devices. its work with single topic but fails when have multiple topics .

**Note : Working with single topic like,**

```
var topic = 'MaleFemale'; // here i have only one topic 
                var message = {
                    android: {
                        ttl: 5*60*1000, // 5 min in milliseconds
                        priority: 'normal',
                        notification: {
                        title: 'Someone want to chat',
                        body: 'Tap to join chat',
                        icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                        color: '#2C5AE1'
                        }
                    },
                    topic: topic
                };

                send.admin.messaging().send(message)
                .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                });
```

**Note : Fails in Multiple topics like,**

```
var topic = "'FemaleAny' in topics || 'MaleAny' in topics";//here i have multiple topic 
                var message = {
                    android: {
                        ttl: 5*60*1000, // 5 min in milliseconds
                        priority: 'normal',
                        notification: {
                        title: 'Someone want to chat',
                        body: 'Tap to join chat',
                        icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                        color: '#2C5AE1'
                        }
                    },
                    condition: topic
                };

                send.admin.messaging().sendToCondition(message)
                .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                });
```

**Error :**

```
throw new error_1.FirebaseMessagingError(error_1.MessagingClientErrorCode.INVALID_RECIPIENT, 'Condition provided to sendToCondition() must be a non-empty string.');
            ^

Error: Condition provided to sendToCondition() must be a non-empty string.
    at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at FirebaseMessagingError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:85:28)
    at new FirebaseMessagingError (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:241:16)
    at Messaging.sendToCondition (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging.js:637:19)
    at manageQueue (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/index.js:268:40)
    at Socket.socket.on (/Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/index.js:25:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at /Users/kdblue/Desktop/Android Projects/ChatApp/server/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:528:12
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

**I tried but not worked for me :-**

1) https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages?authuser=0

2) [What is the correct syntax to send Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to multiple topics via condition](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48652101/6925888)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its little weird , i am giving answer to my question , Anyways
I solved problem by changing method `sendToCondition()` to `send()` .

```
var condition = "'FemaleAny' in topics || 'MaleAny' in topics";
                var message = {
                    android: {
                        ttl: 30*1000, //  30sec in milliseconds
                        priority: 'normal',
                        notification: {
                        title: 'Someone want to chat',
                        body: 'Tap to join chat',
                        icon: 'stock_ticker_update',
                        color: '#2C5AE1',
                        tag: '4'
                        }
                    },
                    condition: condition
                };

                send.admin.messaging().send(message)
                .then((response) => {
                // Response is a message ID string.
                console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                console.log('Error sending message:', error);
                });
```