# TypeError: admin.messaging.sendToTopic is not a function

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am developing an Android application in which I have an Activity, OperatorActivity. It have CardNo and LineNo as EditText and that values are inserted to FirebaseDatabase.

What I want to do is to notify every user who have this App installed of the Update using FCM. I used Note.js and created a function for this but everytime there is an error:

```
TypeError: admin.messaging.sendToTopic is not a function
at exports.sendNotification.functions.database.ref.onWrite.event (/user_code/index.js:18:21)
at cloudFunctionNewSignature (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:105:23)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:135:20)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:733:24
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
```

I am new to Functions so I can't understand how I solve this error.
I have already looked similar questions but none solved my problem.

**index.js**

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("Operator :")
.onWrite(event =>{
    var payload = {
        notification :{
            title : 'Mechanic Needed',
            body: 'Any available mechanic report ASAP',
            sound: 'defaulf',
            badge: '1'
        },
        topic: 'notification'
    };

    admin.messaging.sendToTopic('notification',payload)
    .then(function(response){
        console.log("Successfully sent Message.", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log("Error sending message!", erorr);
    })
    
});
```

I subscribed all the users to 'notification' topic programmatically.

**This is how database looks :**
This is a Dummy database.

[image]

firebase --version : 4.2.1

npm --version : 6.4.1

**EDIT :**
This is working now.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config.firebase);

exports.sendNotificationToUsers = functions.database.ref("Operator :")
.onWrite(event =>{
    var payload = {
        notification: {
                title : 'Mechanic Needed',
                body: 'Any available mechanic report ASAP',
                sound: 'defaulf'
            }
    };

    admin.messaging().sendToTopic('notification',payload)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent Message.", response);
        return;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error sending message!", error);
    })
    
});
```

Comment: try to use send() method instead  sendToTopic() ! , https://stackoverflow.com/a/52333944/6925888

Comment: I tried that too, but same error.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
admin.messaging
```

You need to use this (note from the API docs that [it's a function to call](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.messaging)):

```
admin.messaging()
```

[See also the documentation for sending to a topic.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages#send_to_a_topic). It shows the same usage.